# How to implement the didSelectRow method of the pickerView class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uipickerview

I have never worked with a picker view before. I assume it would be similar to the func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) method of the table view class. However I can not figure out how I will get the text from the picker value and display that in a label. I would like this to be done inside the postListing method.Can someone help me out with this please? Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class BooksViewController: UIViewController , UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var bookImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var coursePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var bookDescription: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var pickerSelectionLabel: UILabel!

    var photoSelected = false
    var activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()


    @IBAction func pickImage(sender: AnyObject) {

        println("pick image pressed")
        var image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        image.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func postListing(sender: AnyObject) {

        var error = ""

        if (photoSelected == false) {

            error = "Please select an image."

        } else if (bookDescription.text == "") {

            error = "Please enter a description"

        }

        if (error != "") {

            displayAlert("Can't Post Image", error: error)

        } else {


            let actIndPoint = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y)

            activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
            activityIndicator.center = actIndPoint
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
            view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            var bookPosting = PFObject(className: "BookPosting")
            bookPosting["Description"] = bookDescription.text
            bookPosting["username"] = PFUser.currentUser().username
            //bookPosting["subject"] = coursePicker

            bookPosting.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

                if (success == false) {

                    self.displayAlert("Can't Post Image", error: "Please try again")

                } else {

                    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.bookImage.image)
                    let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData)

                    bookPosting["imageFile"] = imageFile

                    bookPosting.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                        if (success == false) {

                            self.displayAlert("Can't Post Image", error: "Please try again")

                        } else {

                            println("Successful post!")
                            self.displayAlert("Your image has been posted", error: "Posted Successfully")


                            self.photoSelected = false

                            self.bookImage.image = UIImage(named: "book1.png")

                            self.bookDescription.text = ""



                        }

                    })
                }
            })


        }



        println("post listing pressed")

    }


    func displayAlert(title: String, error: String) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }



    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        bookImage.image = image
        photoSelected = true
    }




    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        return courseCatalog.count

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

        return courseCatalog[row]

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        println("Books view controller")

        super.viewDidLoad()

        photoSelected = false

        bookImage.image = UIImage(named: "book1.png")

        bookDescription.text = ""


    }


}
```

Comment: Check https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the `Delegate` method of select the components from `Picker`

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
 {
   println("\(courseCatalog[row])")
    yourlabelname.text=courseCatalog[row]

}
```

Comment: The same questions asked several times and answered too. So please give them the similar question links and vote to close, instead of answering such poor question. He didn't show any research effort, except that bunch of code.

Comment: Sure my friend, I think the questioner is the fresher or changed some domain from another to iOS , thats y I submit my answer.