# index row didSelectRow selections from UIPickerView

Tags: swift

I want to make an IF-else code based on the index tag of the data I have selected in the picker. For example, 0.if I chose the value ... let this code work, 1.if I choose the value ... I want this code to work. What should I do?

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        getDevice.text = gradePickerValues[row]

        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement the didSelectRow method of the pickerView class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191162/how-to-implement-the-didselectrow-method-of-the-pickerview-class)

Comment: It has nothing to do with my position.

Comment: Could you possibly show the datasource of your picker?  Also, you mention "index tag", which one is it? the index or the object's tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `switch` statement in the function body is easy enough:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    switch row {
      case 0:
        doSomething()
      case 1,
           2:
        doSomethingElseUnderTheIllusionOfDifferenceBetween1And2()
      case 3:
        doSomethingEvenElsier()
      default:
        playRecordingOfAngrySounding80sComputerShoutingErrorError()
        informTheUserThatWeAreFreshOutOfDefaults()
    }

}
```

If you need a more specific answer than Swift control flow, I recommend editing your question and adding more details.

Comment: Some relevant reading: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html